# How to replace a capture group instead of the full match in a RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, markdown

I have this code:

```js
let x = "the *quick* brown fox";

let y = x.replace(/[^\\](\*)(.*)(\*)/g, "<strong>$2</strong>");

console.log(y);
```

It replaces `*quick*` with `<strong>quick</strong>`

The problem is that I also want backslashes to escape it, so that `\*quick*` does not get converted to `<strong>quick</strong>`

I have done this by requiring the previous character not to be a slash in the regex.

Unfortunately, this also gets rid of that character in the result.

So the result ends up being:

`the<strong>quick</strong> brown fox` (notice the missing space)

I thought maybe I could wrap the latter half of the regex in a capture group and replace only that, but as far as I know Javascript's replace function works on the full match only.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm avoiding the use of a full-blown markdown library because I only need to handle a few cases (bolding and italics), so I'm trying to keep it simple.

Comment: You can capture it `([^\\])(\*)(.*)(\*)` and replace with `$1<strong>$3</strong>`, but that wouldn’t be correct either, because the backslash could be escaped itself. Greedy `.*` probably won’t work that well either… and then there’s mixing emphasis markers… you should probably use a library. Or at least write something not based on replacing with regexes.

Comment: Yeah in my testing I noticed `$1<strong>$3</strong>` was really close but not quite it as well. I was kinda hoping I could just fix this one minor issue than have to migrate to a full-blown library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind so that the character isn't included in the match. This will also allow it to match at the beginning of the string (your regexp requires there to be a character before the match).

```js
let x = "the *quick* brown fox";
let y = x.replace(/(?<!\\)(\*)(.*)(\*)/g, "<strong>$2</strong>");
console.log(y);

x = "the \\*quick* brown fox";
y = x.replace(/(?<!\\)(\*)(.*)(\*)/g, "<strong>$2</strong>");
console.log(y);
```

Negative lookbehinds are a new JavaScript feature, if you have to support older browsers, put the character before it into another capture group, and copy it into the replacement. To solve the problem of matching at the beginning, make it match either the beginning of the string or a non-backslash.

```js
let x = "the \\*quick* brown fox";
let y = x.replace(/(^|[^\\])(\*)(.*)(\*)/g, "$1<strong>$3</strong>");
console.log(y);

x = "the *quick* brown fox";
y = x.replace(/(^|[^\\])(\*)(.*)(\*)/g, "$1<strong>$3</strong>");
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Oh cool this works great! Yeah I see negative lookbehind only has 71% browser support. But the alternative solution is only 2 extra characters so might as well just use that? Unless babel converts negative lookbehind to it for you?

Comment: No, babel won't convert this, there are too many complications.

Comment: Okie dokie I will use the second option then. Thank you!

Comment: Ah sorry I think I noticed a problem (although not sure if it's possible to fix?). If you type in a backslash the backslash still exists in the output. Ideally the input of `the \*quick* brown fox` would output `the *quick* brown fox`, (no backslash, no strong), you know?

Comment: Actually nevermind I think I fixed it. Can just do `y = y.replace(/\\/g, "");` after I run it through the regex.